# Can I install Ubuntu in dual boot from inside Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, hp

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. I have tried using a USB flash drive, but it won't boot. I get stuck on the HP loading logo and nothing happens. If I try to launch my boot menu, it goes to the menu screen but doesn't actually launch the boot menu, or even respond to my boot menu key.

I know that it is possible to install Ubuntu from within Windows using Unetbootin on Windows 7, however they mention nothing of Windows 8 or 8.1 support.

So if anyone could give me either a step by step for how to install Ubuntu without a USB or CD for windows 8.1, or a link to something where I can figure it out that'd be much appreciated.

Computer: HP Envy h8-1413c

Either a solution to allow me to boot using a USB flash drive, or a solution to installing inside windows 8.1 would be appreciated!

Comment: From inside windows you have to use something like virtualbox. Otherwise you run only one OS (kernel) at a time.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, I don't want to run Ubuntu inside of Windows 8.1, I just need to install it (like you could do with Unetbootin, or even a usb) to be installed alongside of Windows so I can boot into Ubuntu at startup.

Comment: You are trying to go through hoops to fix something. Answer to the title: no. I would ask a question focusing on getting the bootable usb working ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't install Ubuntu in  inside windows 8.1, like you were able to install it in windows 7 and other older windows versions.
2. However, you can install Ubuntu alongside windows so you can boot into Ubuntu at startup.
   when you are installing ubuntu, you are given an option to install Ubuntu alongside windows.
   Ensure that the USB in on the top of the list in boot menu.

p.s. I am also using ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 and it feels good.

Comment: My problem is I can't seem to create a working bootable USB drive, I have used various software (such as Unetbootin, Universal USB Installer, and Yumi) but every time I am simply stuck at the HP splash screen going nowhere. If you could point me to a way to create a bootable USB I'd be very grateful. As far as using VM I am able to do that, and have done it; however that is not what I am trying to do. -- Also thank you for letting me know I cannot do it as I could in Windows 7

Comment: You are most welcome. 
You can create bootable USB by using pendrive; it is an excellent option.
Here is the link: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/